# ImportError: No module named pjsip

Tags: python, linux, makefile, debian, pjsip

I'm currently trying to set up pjsip and it's python wrapper for a small sip project.
I followed the instructions here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install which basically breaks down to:

1. Check out pjsip from svn
2. Compile pjsip
3. Compile python module

All the commands needed were

```
$ cd your-pjsip-root-dir
$ ./configure && make dep && make
$ cd pjsip-apps/src/python
$ sudo make
```

pjsip and the python wrapper compiled without any errors. But as soon as I want to test it:

```
XXXX@WXXXXX:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pjsua
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pjsua
>>>
```

What do?

(OS is debian wheezy, all dependencies for compilation and python-dev etc. are installed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need do:

```
sudo make install
```

or possibly:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

The best bet would be to read any README files you can find in the download.

Comment: `sudo make install` did the trick. Funny that this is nowhere stated, guess they assumed this is obvious for everyone. :)

Comment: I get ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_pjsua.so, 2): Symbol not found: _pj_atexit anyways after 'sudo make install'

Comment: @loretoparisi - That sort of error normally results from missing the configure step, a library version mismatch or from a missing something-dev install.  Are you __sure__ that you did the first two steps sucessfully.